# Update view from function when function calculate value using the same view

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a View that that contains two columns. Column c1, and column c2.

- c1 is updated by a function `getPrice()`.
- The problem is that get `getPrice()` calculate is´s value by using column c2.

This causes mysql to send out error message :

> ERROR 1424 (HY000): Recursive stored functions and triggers are not allowed

Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: Are you able to replace your function with a procedure, and use INOUT for your return?

Comment: Will try and report back, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Ctc not sure if its possible to call a procedure from a view?

Comment: Sounds like you are using SQL server?  Yup, it is possible, once you create the view, you can call it easily.
http://capnjosh.com/blog/how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-from-a-view-in-sql-server/ will help :)

Comment: @Ctc Im using mysql do you think it´s still possible?

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT` and `UPDATE` can be decoupled through a temporary table: select new values into temporary table and update source table from it.